# Защита от подделывания данных в ajax запросе самим пользователем

Tags: запрос, ajax, клиент, защита, javascript

Всем привет, уже весь инет перерыл. Представим себе такую ситуацию. У нас есть игра на js, в которой пользователь набирает очки. Эти очки нужно сохранить на сервер для создания таблицы рекордов. Рекорд вместе с id пользователя и токеном через ajax передается на php сервер. Если токен защищает аккаунт пользователя от стороннего вмешательства, то как защитить рекорд от замены его самим пользователем? Ведь юзеру ничего не мешает подменить запрос, взяв свой токен, и легко попасть на первое место. Переменная, хранящая текущий результат на клиенте, зашита в функцию-обработчик. Поэтому пользователь ее просто так не изменит. А вот запрос подделает запросто. Какие средства защиты нужно использовать? Помогите!

Comment: если вы не контролируете процесс игры с сервера, то никак. и переменную вашу изменить тоже труда не составит. погуглите про artMoney.

Answer (score 4):

Ну первое, что приходит в голову - обеспечить ситуацию, при которой сервер будет знать, что запрос пришел именно из игры, а не создан искусственно. Предлагаю в игре генерировать некий хеш, завязанный на глобальное время и зашифрованный только вам известным способом. На сервере принимать его, генерировать свой хеш по тому же принципу и сравнивать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я так уже делал. В конец запроса я добавлял md5 от всех параметров плюс timestamp, а на сервере проверял совпадение. Жуликов стало меньше, но они все равно остались. Если генерировать хеш на клиенте, то алгоритм как на ладони. На следующий же день нашел скрипт для подделки результата для моей игры на гитхабе

Comment: md5 - это слишком банально) А пробовали вести внутренний таймер в игре?

Answer (score 3):

Цитата с хабра:

> > Написал метод который дублировал результат. В одном параметре
> > передавался реальный, в другом
> > шифрованный результат, методом замены
> > символа по ключу. А далее, на сервере
> > оба сравниваются и если что-то не
> > соответствует, то – бан по аккаунту.
>
> И еще, сервер отправляет
> сгенрированный ключ при первом
> обращении. Клиент же, должен его
> вернуть с результатом. Без этого
> ключа, результат не примется и если
> все соответствует, и все проходит
> проверку, то результат записывается в
> БД, и генерируется новый ключ, который
> опять отдается клиенту. Это сделано
> для того, чтобы повторно запрос с
> результатом не могли отправить, как
> делается в программе «Charles».

Comment: А можно ссылку на пост, плиз?)

Comment: @Fuzz: www.google.com?

Comment: Способ ещё актуален?